# Can we get Custom label in Omniscript

Tags: apex, customlabel, omnistudio, vlocity

I have created a custom label. I need to get a custom label in the Omniscript. can we do that in the Omniscript? or do we need any other method to pass a custom label to the Omniscript? Or do we need to use any apex class to pass this custom label to the Omniscript?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can not access custom labels in omniscript like we can do in flexcards or LWC. You can use it inside a text block but not in the element label or else where. Please read the note point in the doc
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_define_custom_label_translations_in_multi_language_omniscripts_20774.htm&type=5